# libm link issue in gcc 4.6.3

Tags: c, linux, math, gcc, linker

The linking of math.lib using -lm is working is a different manner in gcc 4.6.3.

It use to work **gcc -lm file.c** but in **gcc 4.6.3** its **gcc file.c -lm**.

What is the reason for this change? Or is it a bug?

Thanks

This is a part of the code.

```
    float i = 100;
    printf("%f", sqrt(i));
    return 0;
```

I complied like this

gcc -lm mat.c

/tmp/ccPxTEjS.o: In function `main':

mat.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `sqrt'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Operating System : Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: This really surprises me. Are you sure? What actually happens if you run `gcc -lm file.c` on 4.6.3?  You didn't specify what the problem is.

Comment: The question stands. What happens?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Changes made in the question with the sample code.

Comment: http://nick.zoic.org/art/etc/gcc-linker-libs.html

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks. Do you know the reason?

Comment: @AnishChandran: I looked around and there are conflicting conclusion: some blaming gcc and some blaming the binutil linker. I don't know the exact answer myself. Probably what Basile Starynkevitch suggested is correct.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks!!! I appreciate your effort. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You said you tried to compile it as:

```
gcc -lm mat.c
```

Some configurations of gcc require strict ordering of options, which requires libraries to come after the source code that uses them:

```
gcc mat.c -lm
```

Does this work?

Comment: **Most configurations** of `gcc` on Linux **require** the libraries to come after the source code. And this was always true on Linux and other Unixes. It has not changed since dozens of years.

Comment: This has less to do with GCC and more to do with Binutils.  On OS X, GCC is common but Binutils is not, and you can specify libraries in any order.